# import shapefile to postgis with customized projection using ogr2ogr2

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, coordinate-system

I have a shapefile with a customized projection

```
PROJCS["NAD83_Lambert_Conformal_Conic_CN",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["Geodetic_Reference_System_of_1980",6378137,298.2572221008916]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",33],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",60],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",43],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-96],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

I have read the projection string and define a customized projection system

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text,srtext) values ( 94326, 'epsg', 94326, '+proj=lcc +lat_1=33 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=43 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs', 'PROJCS["NAD83_Lambert_Conformal_Conic_CN",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["Geodetic_Reference_System_of_1980",6378137,298.2572221008916]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",33],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",60],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",43],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-96],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]');
```

However, ogr2ogr2 cannot interpret my newly define projection

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=1.1.1.1 user=geotest dbname=dbname password=password" LRS_DATUM.shp -a_srs "EPSG:94326"
```

returns

```
ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 94326 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a val
id EPSG coordinate system?
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: GDAL has its own projection library and it can't use the projection that you have defined on the PostGIS side only. It is quite hard for a user to add EPSG synonyms into GDAL. I would try what happens if you use ogr2ogr simply with your Proj4 string `-a_srs '+proj=lcc +lat_1=33 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=43 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs'`. It probably adds a new line into spatial_ref_system for you.

Comment: It seems that I can use a orc_text file to define a customized projection http://gothos.info/2009/04/transform-projections-with-gdal-ogr/ . I will explore this option and see if I can solve this problem.